# Laravel 6 Horizon Redis Exception

Tags: laravel, redis, predis, phpredis

I have an issue with my Laravel app - many errors in log like that:

> READONLY You can't write against a read-only replica.
>   {"exception":"[object] (RedisException(code: 0): READONLY You can't
>   write against a read-only replica. at
>   /var/www/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connections/PhpRedisConnection.php:30

I'm using **predis** and **laravel/horizon**, but with **phpredis** it fails too. My queued jobs working well, but sometimes it fails with that error.

I am using:
Laravel 6 (QUEUE_CONNECTION = redis)
Laravel Horizon + Supervisord
Default Redis installation

I haven't any idea... Is this problem with Redis?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Re-installing redis-server seems to have helped for now.